# Яндекс.Карты не работает MinZoom, MaxZoom

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Версия 2.1 Не работает ограничение на масштаб. Что я написал не так?

```
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [globSH, globD],
            zoom: globZOOM,
            controls: ['typeSelector', 'zoomControl'],
            iconImageHref: '/assets/img/16.gif'
        }, {
            MinZoom: 11,
            MaxZoom: 17
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript чувствителен к регистру:

```
minZoom: 11,
maxZoom: 17
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то взял пример с 1.1, а там было что-то типа LayerMinZoom. Layer-то я убрал... Теперь работает!

Comment: @Serg_pnz рада помочь, вы можете отметить ответ как правильный (зеленая галочка)